# How can I improve the speed of a query?

Tags: postgis

I have this query which takes around 110ms to execute in symfony.

The 1st error I find is that the index is a btree and not a gist, how can I tell doctrine to use a gist index?

```
#[ORM\Index(name: 'index_geog', columns: ['geog'])]

[...]
 #[ORM\Column(type: PostGISType::GEOGRAPHY, nullable: true)]
    private string $geog;
```

here is the query and the analysis:

```
SELECT
  p0_.id AS id_0,
  p0_.titre AS titre_1,
  p0_.latitude AS latitude_2,
  p0_.longitude AS longitude_3,
  ST_AsEWKT(p0_.geog) AS geog_4,
  
  ST_Distance(
    p0_.geog,
    ST_Point(?, ?)
  ) AS sclr_13
FROM
  fiche p0_
ORDER BY
  p0_.geog <-> ST_Point(?, ?) ASC
LIMIT
  9


Limit  (cost=4408.87..4647.49 rows=9 width=1992)
  ->  Result  (cost=4408.87..230109.79 rows=8513 width=1992)
        ->  Sort  (cost=4408.87..4430.16 rows=8513 width=1984)
              Sort Key: ((geog <-> '0101000020E61000000000000000001C400000000000804840'::geography))
              ->  Seq Scan on fiche p0_  (cost=0.00..4231.38 rows=8513 width=1984)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with doctrine, but I do not believe it is possible to tell a client to specifically use a certain index. You have to create it in the database and depending on the query the planer will chose it - or not. If the index type is wrong, drop it and create a new one. Btw, a query without a WHERE clause is pretty hard to optimize ;)

Comment: hum ok so I'm going to change it in the migration file but indeed, to go from btree to gist I already went to 19 ms